# Dimension of a Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, physics

How can I prove that:

$\dim(M_1\vec{\oplus}M_2\vec{\oplus}\ldots\vec{\oplus}M_n) = \dim(M_1) + \dim(M_2) + \ldots + \dim(M_m)$

Where $M_i\lt L,\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and $\vec{\oplus}$ is the direct sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be subspaces of vector space $V$.
We show first that
$$
\dim(U_1 \oplus U_2) = \dim(U_1) + \dim(U_2) \; .
$$
Let $(v_1, \ldots v_n)$ a basis of $U_1$ and $(w_1, \ldots, w_m)$ a basis of $U_2$.
We can show that $(v_1, \ldots, v_n, w_1, \ldots, w_m)$ is a basis of $U_1 \oplus U_2$.

You have to check two things:

1. Let $u \in U_1 \oplus U_2$. Then there are scalars $\alpha_1, \ldots,\alpha_n, \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_m$, such that
   $$
   u = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i + \sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j w_j \; .
   $$
2. The vectors $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n, w_1, \ldots, w_m\}$ are linearly independent, i.e.
   $$
   \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i + \sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j w_j = 0 \quad \implies \quad
   \alpha_1 = \ldots = \alpha_n = \beta_1 = \ldots = \beta_m = 0
   $$

Finally, you can use induction to show the general case.